# Rename file name in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm finding information on how to change sheet names and even naming and placing copies of files in Drive but is there any simple way to just have the string in a cell be added to the file name (no copies, just replacing the current one)? I have a script to clear certain cells, and this cell would be included so it's planned that this file name would then go back to the default title after the clearing. Sorry for not having any example to share because I'm not sure what I should start with.

To clarify: The reason for this is because we download the sheet after we're done filling it out and then clear it for the next task. This would be just to help automate the task of adding a case number to the file name for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly, but I think this should do it. You add the value from cell A1 (= row 1, column 1) into the tittle of your current active spreadsheet.

```html
function changeSpeadsheetName() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).getValue(); //assuming you want to add the string in A1 to your title
  
  var name = sheet.rename('I renamed my spreadsheet into ' + range);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that :)

Comment: I thought I commented this already but it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This function will  allow you to set your spreadsheet File Name:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('CaseMenu')
  .addItem('Change Case Number', 'changeCaseNumber')
  .addToUi();
}

function changeCaseNumber() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Cases');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var tObj={};
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    tObj[r[0]]=r[1];
  });
  let r=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Get Case Number", "Enter Case Number", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(r.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    tObj.number=r.getResponseText();
    //DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).setName(Utilities.formatString('%s - %s',tObj.prefix,tObj.number));
    ss.rename(Utilities.formatString('%s - %s',tObj.prefix,tObj.number));
    setCases(tObj);
  }
}

function setCases(dfltObj){
  var dfltH=Object.keys(dfltObj).length;
  if(dfltObj){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Cases');
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,dfltH,2);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<dfltH;i++){
      vA[i][1]=dfltObj[vA[i][0]];
    }
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

I use a hidden sheet to create this table:

[image]

You can use the prefix to set the beginning of you Spreadsheet title and then you can run the function changeCaseNumber() to change the second portion of your spreadsheet name.

And if you wish you can modify the exact string configuration fairly easily because I used Utilties.formatString() to build the title and it uses sprintf format which is familiar to many programmers.  It also records you last case number and your current base title.  You can change it easily by going into the spreadsheet 'Cases' if you wish.